# Zlib Error Message

Tags: zlib

I have a "zlib error" message as I'm playing an old school RPG called "Laxius Power" on Windows XP. It just kicks me out of the game! How can I fix it?

Comment: At least post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Zlib is a compression library.  Perhaps your game uses some data files that are stored compressed on disk, and one of those files is corrupt or missing.  If the error happens when you start the game, there's a chance that's the problem.  If the error happens during game-play, who knows.